# How to recursively find gaps where 90 days passed, between rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, recursive

This is a kind of trivial task in my C# homeworld, but I don't yet make it in SQL and would prefer to solve it set-based (without cursors). A resultset should come from a query like this.

```
SELECT SomeId, MyDate, 
    dbo.udfLastHitRecursive(param1, param2, MyDate) as 'Qualifying'
FROM T
```

**How should it work**

> I send those three params into a UDF.
>   The UDF internally use params to fetch related <= 90 days older rows, from a view.
>   The UDF traverse 'MyDate' and return 1 if it should be included in a total calculation.
>   If it should not, then it return 0. 
>   Named here as "qualifying".

**What the udf will do**

> List the rows in date order. 
>   Calculate the days between rows. 
>   First row in resultset defaults to Hit = 1. 
>   If the difference is up to 90, 
>    - then pass to next row until the sum of gaps is 90 days (90th day must pass)
>   When reached, set Hit to 1 and reset gap to 0. 
>   It would also work to instead omit the row from result.

```
                                          |(column by udf, which not work yet)
Date              Calc_date     MaxDiff   | Qualifying
2014-01-01 11:00  2014-01-01    0         | 1
2014-01-03 10:00  2014-01-01    2         | 0
2014-01-04 09:30  2014-01-03    1         | 0
2014-04-01 10:00  2014-01-04    87        | 0
2014-05-01 11:00  2014-04-01    30        | 1
```

In the table above, MaxDiff column is the gap from date in previous line. The problem with my attempts so far is that I can't ignore second last row in the sample above.

**[EDIT]**
As per comment I add a tag and also paste the udf I have compiled just now. Though, is just a placeholder and won't give useful result.

```
;WITH cte (someid, otherkey, mydate, cost) AS
(
    SELECT someid, otherkey, mydate, cost
    FROM dbo.vGetVisits
    WHERE someid = @someid AND VisitCode = 3 AND otherkey = @otherkey 
    AND CONVERT(Date,mydate) = @VisitDate

    UNION ALL

    SELECT top 1 e.someid, e.otherkey, e.mydate, e.cost
    FROM dbo.vGetVisits AS E
    WHERE CONVERT(date, e.mydate) 
        BETWEEN DateAdd(dd,-90,CONVERT(Date,@VisitDate)) AND CONVERT(Date,@VisitDate)
        AND e.someid = @someid AND e.VisitCode = 3 AND e.otherkey = @otherkey 
        AND CONVERT(Date,e.mydate) = @VisitDate
        order by e.mydate
)
```

I have another query which I define separately which is more close to what I need, but blocked with the fact I can't calculate on windowed columns. I also tried one similiar which give more or less same output just with a LAG() over MyDate, surrounded with a datediff.

```
SELECT
    t.Mydate, t.VisitCode, t.Cost, t.SomeId, t.otherkey, t.MaxDiff, t.DateDiff
FROM 
(
    SELECT *,
        MaxDiff = LAST_VALUE(Diff.Diff)  OVER (
            ORDER BY Diff.Mydate ASC
                ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT *,
            Diff =  ISNULL(DATEDIFF(DAY, LAST_VALUE(r.Mydate) OVER (
                        ORDER BY r.Mydate ASC
                            ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING), 
                                r.Mydate),0),
            DateDiff =  ISNULL(LAST_VALUE(r.Mydate) OVER (
                        ORDER BY r.Mydate ASC
                            ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING), 
                                r.Mydate)
        FROM dbo.vGetVisits AS r
        WHERE r.VisitCode = 3 AND r.SomeId = @SomeID AND r.otherkey = @otherkey
    ) AS Diff
) AS t
WHERE t.VisitCode = 3 AND t.SomeId = @SomeId AND t.otherkey = @otherkey
    AND t.Diff <= 90
ORDER BY
    t.Mydate ASC;
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64640/discussion-on-question-by-independent-how-to-recursively-find-gaps-where-90-days).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As I read the question, the basic recursive algorithm required is:

1. Return the row with the earliest date in the set
2. Set that date as "current"
3. Find the row with the earliest date more than 90 days after the current date
4. Repeat from step 2 until no more rows are found

This is relatively easy to implement with a recursive common table expression.

For example, using the following sample data (based on the question):

```
DECLARE @T AS table (TheDate datetime PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT @T (TheDate)
VALUES
    ('2014-01-01 11:00'),
    ('2014-01-03 10:00'),
    ('2014-01-04 09:30'),
    ('2014-04-01 10:00'),
    ('2014-05-01 11:00'),
    ('2014-07-01 09:00'),
    ('2014-07-31 08:00');
```

The recursive code is:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    -- Anchor:
    -- Start with the earliest date in the table
    SELECT TOP (1)
        T.TheDate
    FROM @T AS T
    ORDER BY
        T.TheDate

    UNION ALL

    -- Recursive part   
    SELECT
        SQ1.TheDate
    FROM 
    (
        -- Recursively find the earliest date that is 
        -- more than 90 days after the "current" date
        -- and set the new date as "current".
        -- ROW_NUMBER + rn = 1 is a trick to get
        -- TOP in the recursive part of the CTE
        SELECT
            T.TheDate,
            rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                ORDER BY T.TheDate)
        FROM CTE
        JOIN @T AS T
            ON T.TheDate > DATEADD(DAY, 90, CTE.TheDate)
    ) AS SQ1
    WHERE
        SQ1.rn = 1
)
SELECT 
    CTE.TheDate 
FROM CTE
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

The results are:

```
╔═════════════════════════╗
║         TheDate         ║
╠═════════════════════════╣
║ 2014-01-01 11:00:00.000 ║
║ 2014-05-01 11:00:00.000 ║
║ 2014-07-31 08:00:00.000 ║
╚═════════════════════════╝
```

With an index having `TheDate` as a leading key, the execution plan is very efficient:

[image: Execution plan]

You could choose to wrap this in a function and execute it directly against the view mentioned in the question, but my instincts are against it. Usually, performance is better when you select rows from a view into a temporary table, provide the appropriate index on the temporary table, then apply the logic above. The details depend on the details of the view, but this is my general experience.

For completeness (and prompted by ypercube's answer) I should mention that my other go-to solution for this type of problem (until T-SQL gets proper ordered set functions) is a SQLCLR cursor ([see my answer here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/64223/1192) for an example of the technique). This performs *much* better than a T-SQL cursor, and is convenient for those with skills in .NET languages and the ability to run SQLCLR in their production environment. It may not offer much in this scenario over the recursive solution because the majority of the cost is the sort, but it is worth mentioning.

Answer (score 10):

Since this *is* a SQL Server 2014 question I might as well add a natively compiled stored procedure version of a "cursor".

Source table with some data:

```
create table T 
(
  TheDate datetime primary key
);

go

insert into T(TheDate) values
('2014-01-01 11:00'),
('2014-01-03 10:00'),
('2014-01-04 09:30'),
('2014-04-01 10:00'),
('2014-05-01 11:00'),
('2014-07-01 09:00'),
('2014-07-31 08:00');
```

A table type that is the parameter to the stored procedure. [Adjust the `bucket_count` appropriately](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn494956.aspx).

```
create type TType as table
(
  ID int not null primary key nonclustered hash with (bucket_count = 16),
  TheDate datetime not null
) with (memory_optimized = on);
```

And a stored procedure that loops through the table valued parameter and collects the rows in `@R`.

```
create procedure dbo.GetDates
  @T dbo.TType readonly
with native_compilation, schemabinding, execute as owner 
as
begin atomic with (transaction isolation level = snapshot, language = N'us_english', delayed_durability = on)

  declare @R dbo.TType;
  declare @ID int = 0;
  declare @RowsLeft bit = 1;  
  declare @CurDate datetime = '1901-01-01';
  declare @LastDate datetime = '1901-01-01';

  while @RowsLeft = 1
  begin
    set @ID += 1;

    select @CurDate = T.TheDate
    from @T as T
    where T.ID = @ID

    if @@rowcount = 1
    begin
      if datediff(day, @LastDate, @CurDate) > 90
      begin
        insert into @R(ID, TheDate) values(@ID, @CurDate);
        set @LastDate = @CurDate;
      end;
    end
    else
    begin
      set @RowsLeft = 0;
    end

  end;

  select R.TheDate
  from @R as R;
end
```

Code to fill a memory optimized table variable that is used as a parameter to the natively compiled stored procedure and call the procedure.

```
declare @T dbo.TType;

insert into @T(ID, TheDate)
select row_number() over(order by T.TheDate),
       T.TheDate
from T;

exec dbo.GetDates @T;
```

Result:

```
TheDate
-----------------------
2014-07-31 08:00:00.000
2014-01-01 11:00:00.000
2014-05-01 11:00:00.000
```

Update:

If you for some reason don't need to visit every row in the table you can do the equivalent of the "jump to next date" version that is implemented in the recursive CTE by Paul White.

The data type does not need the ID column and you should not use a hash index.

```
create type TType as table
(
  TheDate datetime not null primary key nonclustered
) with (memory_optimized = on);
```

And the stored procedure uses a `select top(1) ..` to find the next value.

```
create procedure dbo.GetDates
  @T dbo.TType readonly
with native_compilation, schemabinding, execute as owner 
as
begin atomic with (transaction isolation level = snapshot, language = N'us_english', delayed_durability = on)

  declare @R dbo.TType;
  declare @RowsLeft bit = 1;  
  declare @CurDate datetime = '1901-01-01';

  while @RowsLeft = 1
  begin

    select top(1) @CurDate = T.TheDate
    from @T as T
    where T.TheDate > dateadd(day, 90, @CurDate)
    order by T.TheDate;

    if @@rowcount = 1
    begin
      insert into @R(TheDate) values(@CurDate);
    end
    else
    begin
      set @RowsLeft = 0;
    end

  end;

  select R.TheDate
  from @R as R;
end
```

Comment: Your solutions using DATEADD and DATEDIFF may return different results depending on initial dataset.

Comment: @PavelNefyodov I don't see that. Can you explain or give an example?

Comment: Could you check it on dates like this ('2014-01-01 00:00:00.000'), ('2014-04-01 01:00:00.000'), please? More info can be found in my answer.

Comment: @PavelNefyodov Ah, I see. So if I change the second to `T.TheDate >= dateadd(day, 91, @CurDate)` all would be fine right?

Comment: Or if appropriate to OP, change the datatype of `TheDate` in `TType` to `Date`.

Comment: Changing to >=dateadd(day, 91,) won't  work I think. Changing datatype to DATE should make solutions equivalent. But... will it be correct answer? It depends on what is actually meant by '90 days gap'.

Comment: @PavelNefyodov In this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/28aa1/1) it looks like it is working as expected. And I don't think that if day 90 should be included or not is very important here. Easily adjusted by OP to match what ever rule he needs to match.

Answer (score 5):

A solution that uses a cursor.
*(first, some needed tables and variables)*:

```
-- a table to hold the results
DECLARE @cd TABLE
(   TheDate datetime PRIMARY KEY,
    Qualify INT NOT NULL
);

-- some variables
DECLARE
    @TheDate DATETIME,
    @diff INT,
    @Qualify     INT = 0,
    @PreviousCheckDate DATETIME = '1900-01-01 00:00:00' ;
```

**The actual cursor:**

```
-- declare the cursor
DECLARE c CURSOR
    LOCAL STATIC FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY
    FOR
    SELECT TheDate
      FROM T
      ORDER BY TheDate ;

-- using the cursor to fill the @cd table
OPEN c ;

FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @TheDate ;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @diff = DATEDIFF(day, @PreviousCheckDate, @Thedate) ;
    SET @Qualify = CASE WHEN @diff > 90 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ;

    INSERT @cd (TheDate, Qualify)
        SELECT @TheDate, @Qualify ;

    SET @PreviousCheckDate = 
            CASE WHEN @diff > 90 
                THEN @TheDate 
                ELSE @PreviousCheckDate END ;

    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @TheDate ;
END

CLOSE c;
DEALLOCATE c;
```

**And getting the results:**

```
-- get the results
SELECT TheDate, Qualify
    FROM @cd
    -- WHERE Qualify = 1        -- optional, to see only the qualifying rows
    ORDER BY TheDate ;
```

Tested at **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a68d7/12)**

Comment: Thank's ypercube. As expected fast on limited amount of rows. On 13000 rows, The CTE and this performed more or less the same. On 130.000 rows there was a 600% difference. On 13m it pass 15 minutes on my test equipment. Also I did have to remove the primary key, which may affect performance a little.

Comment: Thnx for testing. You may also test by modifying to do `INSERT @cd` only when `@Qualify=1` (and thus not inserting 13M rows if you don't need all of them in the output). And the solution depends on finding an index on `TheDate`. If there isn't one, it won't be efficient.

Comment: Good point (the datefield have an index, though not pk/unique, not ordered or so). I added if (@Qualify = 1) and the query perform slightly better on 130k. The primary key can work on the challenge-scenario because one patient hardly visit the doctor the same date, hour and minute, twice. Good to see proof that Cursors is not neccessary evil! But still compete CLR. I tried the 13m table again, to see if it could go below o(N) and it did! Just 4min20sec. Nice!

Answer (score 2):

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[vGetVisits]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [dbo].[vGetVisits]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[vGetVisits](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [mydate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_vGetVisits] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)
)

GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[vGetVisits]([id], [mydate])
VALUES
    (1, '2014-01-01 11:00'),
    (2, '2014-01-03 10:00'),
    (3, '2014-01-04 09:30'),
    (4, '2014-04-01 10:00'),
    (5, '2014-05-01 11:00'),
    (6, '2014-07-01 09:00'),
    (7, '2014-07-31 08:00');
GO


-- Clean up 
IF OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.udfLastHitRecursive', N'FN') IS NOT NULL
DROP FUNCTION udfLastHitRecursive;
GO

-- Actual Function  
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udfLastHitRecursive
( @MyDate datetime)

RETURNS TINYINT

AS
    BEGIN 
        -- Your returned value 1 or 0
        DECLARE @Returned_Value TINYINT;
        SET @Returned_Value=0;
    -- Prepare gaps table to be used.
    WITH gaps AS
    (
                        -- Select Date and MaxDiff from the original table
                        SELECT 
                        CONVERT(Date,mydate) AS [date]
                        , DATEDIFF(day,ISNULL(LAG(mydate, 1) OVER (ORDER BY mydate), mydate) , mydate) AS [MaxDiff]
                        FROM dbo.vGetVisits
    )

        SELECT @Returned_Value=
            (SELECT DISTINCT -- DISTINCT in case we have same date but different time
                    CASE WHEN
                     (
                    -- It is a first entry
                    [date]=(SELECT MIN(CONVERT(Date,mydate)) FROM dbo.vGetVisits))
                    OR 
                    /* 
                    --Gap between last qualifying date and entered is greater than 90 
                        Calculate Running sum upto and including required date 
                        and find a remainder of division by 91. 
                    */
                     ((SELECT SUM(t1.MaxDiff)  
                    FROM (SELECT [MaxDiff] FROM gaps WHERE [date]<=t2.[date] 
                    ) t1 
                    )%91 - 
                    /* 
                        ISNULL added to include first value that always returns NULL 
                        Calculate Running sum upto and NOT including required date 
                        and find a remainder of division by 91 
                    */
                    ISNULL((SELECT SUM(t1.MaxDiff)  
                    FROM (SELECT [MaxDiff] FROM gaps WHERE [date]<t2.[date] 
                    ) t1 
                    )%91, 0) -- End ISNULL
                     <0 )
                    /* End Running sum upto and including required date */
                    OR
                    -- Gap between two nearest dates is greater than 90 
                    ((SELECT SUM(t1.MaxDiff)  
                    FROM (SELECT [MaxDiff] FROM gaps WHERE [date]<=t2.[date] 
                    ) t1 
                    ) - ISNULL((SELECT SUM(t1.MaxDiff)  
                    FROM (SELECT [MaxDiff] FROM gaps WHERE [date]<t2.[date] 
                    ) t1 
                    ), 0) > 90) 
                    THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                    END 
                    AS [Qualifying]
                    FROM gaps t2
                    WHERE [date]=CONVERT(Date,@MyDate))
        -- What is neccesary to return when entered date is not in dbo.vGetVisits?
        RETURN @Returned_Value
    END
GO

SELECT 
dbo.udfLastHitRecursive(mydate) AS [Qualifying]
, [id]
, mydate 
FROM dbo.vGetVisits
ORDER BY mydate
```

Result

[image]

Also have a look at [How to Calculate Running Total in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860966/calculate-a-running-total-in-sqlserver)

update: please see below the results of performance testing.

Because of the different logic used in finding "90 days gap" ypercube's and my solutions if left intact may return different results to Paul White's solution.
This is due to the use of [DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189794.aspx) and [DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) functions respectively.

For example:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 90, '2014-01-01 00:00:00.000')
```

returns '2014-04-01 00:00:00.000' meaning that '2014-04-01 01:00:00.000' is beyond 90 days gap

but

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, '2014-01-01 00:00:00.000', '2014-04-01 01:00:00.000')
```

Returns '90' meaning that it is still within the gap.

Consider an example of a retailer. In this case selling a perishable product that has sell by date
'2014-01-01' at '2014-01-01 23:59:59:999' is fine. So value DATEDIFF(DAY, ...) in this case is OK.

Another example is a patient waiting to be seen.
For someone who comes at '2014-01-01 00:00:00:000' and leaves at
'2014-01-01 23:59:59:999' it is 0(zero) days if DATEDIFF is used even though the actual wait was almost 24 hours.
Again patient that comes at '2014-01-01 23:59:59' and walks away at '2014-01-02 00:00:01' waited for a day if DATEDIFF is used.

But I digress.

I left DATEDIFF solutions and even performance tested those but they should really be in their own league.

Also it was noted that for the big datasets it is impossible to avoid same day values.
So if we have say 13 Million records spanning 2 years of data then we will end up
having more than one record for some days. Those records are being filtered out at
the earliest opportunity in my and ypercube's DATEDIFF solutions. Hope ypercube does not mind this.

Solutions were tested on the following table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[vGetVisits](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [mydate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
)
```

with two different clustered indexes (mydate in this case):

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CI_mydate on vGetVisits(mydate) 
GO
```

Table was populated in the following way

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.vGetVisits(id, mydate)
VALUES (1, '01/01/1800')
GO

DECLARE @i bigint
SET @i=2

DECLARE @MaxRows bigint
SET @MaxRows=13001

WHILE @i<@MaxRows 
BEGIN
INSERT INTO dbo.vGetVisits(id, mydate)
VALUES (@i, DATEADD(day,FLOOR(RAND()*(3)),(SELECT MAX(mydate) FROM dbo.vGetVisits)))
SET @i=@i+1
END
```

For a multimillion row case INSERT was changed in a such way that 0-20 minutes entries were randomly added.

All solutions were carefully wrapped up in the following code

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO

DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME

SET @StartDate = GETDATE()

--- Code goes here

PRINT 'Total milliseconds: ' + CONVERT(varchar, DATEDIFF(ms, @StartDate, GETDATE()))
```

Actual codes tested (in no particular order):

Ypercube's DATEDIFF solution (**YPC, DATEDIFF**)

```
DECLARE @cd TABLE
(   TheDate datetime PRIMARY KEY,
    Qualify INT NOT NULL
);

DECLARE
    @TheDate DATETIME,
    @Qualify     INT = 0,
    @PreviousCheckDate DATETIME = '1799-01-01 00:00:00' 


DECLARE c CURSOR
    LOCAL STATIC FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY
    FOR
SELECT 
   mydate
FROM 
 (SELECT
       RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY cast(mydate as date) ORDER BY mydate)
       , mydate
   FROM 
       dbo.vGetVisits) Actions
WHERE
   RowNum = 1
ORDER BY 
  mydate;

OPEN c ;

FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @TheDate ;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    SET @Qualify = CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, @PreviousCheckDate, @Thedate) > 90 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ;
    IF  @Qualify=1
    BEGIN
        INSERT @cd (TheDate, Qualify)
        SELECT @TheDate, @Qualify ;
        SET @PreviousCheckDate=@TheDate 
    END
    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @TheDate ;
END

CLOSE c;
DEALLOCATE c;


SELECT TheDate
    FROM @cd
    ORDER BY TheDate ;
```

Ypercube's DATEADD solution (**YPC, DATEADD**)

```
DECLARE @cd TABLE
(   TheDate datetime PRIMARY KEY,
    Qualify INT NOT NULL
);

DECLARE
    @TheDate DATETIME,
    @Next_Date DATETIME,
    @Interesting_Date DATETIME,
    @Qualify     INT = 0

DECLARE c CURSOR
    LOCAL STATIC FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY
    FOR
  SELECT 
  [mydate]
  FROM [test].[dbo].[vGetVisits]
  ORDER BY mydate
  ;

OPEN c ;

FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @TheDate ;

SET @Interesting_Date=@TheDate

INSERT @cd (TheDate, Qualify)
SELECT @TheDate, @Qualify ;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    IF @TheDate>DATEADD(DAY, 90, @Interesting_Date)
    BEGIN
        INSERT @cd (TheDate, Qualify)
        SELECT @TheDate, @Qualify ;
        SET @Interesting_Date=@TheDate;
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @TheDate;
END

CLOSE c;
DEALLOCATE c;


SELECT TheDate
    FROM @cd
    ORDER BY TheDate ;
```

Paul White's solution (**PW**)

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT TOP (1)
        T.[mydate]
    FROM dbo.vGetVisits AS T
    ORDER BY
        T.[mydate]

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        SQ1.[mydate]
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT
            T.[mydate],
            rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                ORDER BY T.[mydate])
        FROM CTE
        JOIN dbo.vGetVisits AS T
            ON T.[mydate] > DATEADD(DAY, 90, CTE.[mydate])
    ) AS SQ1
    WHERE
        SQ1.rn = 1
)

SELECT 
    CTE.[mydate]
FROM CTE
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

My DATEADD solution (**PN, DATEADD**)

```
DECLARE @cd TABLE
(   TheDate datetime PRIMARY KEY
);

DECLARE @TheDate DATETIME

SET @TheDate=(SELECT MIN(mydate) as mydate FROM [dbo].[vGetVisits])

WHILE (@TheDate IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN

        INSERT @cd (TheDate) SELECT @TheDate;

        SET @TheDate=(  
            SELECT MIN(mydate) as mydate 
            FROM [dbo].[vGetVisits]
            WHERE mydate>DATEADD(DAY, 90, @TheDate)
                    )
    END

SELECT TheDate
    FROM @cd
    ORDER BY TheDate ;
```

My DATEDIFF Solution (**PN, DATEDIFF**)

```
DECLARE @MinDate DATETIME;
SET @MinDate=(SELECT MIN(mydate) FROM dbo.vGetVisits);
    ;WITH gaps AS
    (
       SELECT 
       t1.[date]
       , t1.[MaxDiff]
       , SUM(t1.[MaxDiff]) OVER (ORDER BY t1.[date]) AS [Running Total]
            FROM
            (
                SELECT 
                mydate AS [date]
                , DATEDIFF(day,LAG(mydate, 1, mydate) OVER (ORDER BY mydate) , mydate) AS [MaxDiff] 
                FROM 
                    (SELECT
                    RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY cast(mydate as date) ORDER BY mydate)
                    , mydate
                    FROM dbo.vGetVisits
                    ) Actions
                WHERE RowNum = 1
            ) t1
    )

    SELECT [date]
    FROM gaps t2
    WHERE                         
         ( ([Running Total])%91 - ([Running Total]- [MaxDiff])%91 <0 )      
         OR
         ( [MaxDiff] > 90) 
         OR
         ([date]=@MinDate)    
    ORDER BY [date]
```

I am using SQL Server 2012, so apologies to Mikael Eriksson, but his code won't be tested here. I would still expect his solutions with DATADIFF and DATEADD to return different values on some datasets.

And the actual results are:
[image]

Comment: Thank's Pavel. I didn't really get a result of your solution within time. I tiny down my testdata to 1000 rows until I got a execution time on 25 sec. When I added a group by date and convert to dates in the select, I got the correct output! Just for the sake, I let the query go on with my small-testdata-table (13k rows) and got over 12 minutes, which mean a performance of more then o(n x)! So it looks useful for sets that for sure will be small.

Comment: What was the table you used in tests? How many rows? Not sure why you had to add group by date to get correct output though. Please feel free to publish your fundings as a part of your question (updated).

Comment: Hi! I will add that tomorrow. The group by was to combine duplicate dates. But I was in hurry (late night) and perhaps it was already done by adding convert(date,z). The quantity of rows is in my comment. I tried 1000 rows with your solution. Also tried 13.000 rows with 12 minutes execution. Pauls and Ypercubes was also tempted to the 130.000 and 13millions table.  The table was a plain table with random dates created from yesterday and -2 years back. Clustured index on the date field.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, did I miss something or why would you not just skip recursion and join back to yourself? If the date is the primary key, it must be unique, and in chronological order if you plan on calculating the offset to the next row

```
    DECLARE @T AS TABLE
  (
     TheDate DATETIME PRIMARY KEY
  );

INSERT @T
       (TheDate)
VALUES ('2014-01-01 11:00'),
       ('2014-01-03 10:00'),
       ('2014-01-04 09:30'),
       ('2014-04-01 10:00'),
       ('2014-05-01 11:00'),
       ('2014-07-01 09:00'),
       ('2014-07-31 08:00');

SELECT [T1].[TheDate]                               [first],
       [T2].[TheDate]                               [next],
       Datediff(day, [T1].[TheDate], [T2].[TheDate])[offset],
       ( CASE
           WHEN Datediff(day, [T1].[TheDate], [T2].[TheDate]) >= 30 THEN 1
           ELSE 0
         END )                                      [qualify]
FROM   @T[T1]
       LEFT JOIN @T[T2]
              ON [T2].[TheDate] = (SELECT Min([TheDate])
                                   FROM   @T
                                   WHERE  [TheDate] > [T1].[TheDate])
```

Yields

[image]

Unless I totally missed something important....

Comment: You probably want to change that `WHERE  [TheDate] > [T1].[TheDate]` to take into account the 90 days difference threshold. But still, your output is not the wanted one.

Comment: Important: Your code should have "90" somewhere.