# How to get 5min date interval from stock data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

i have a stock data of comapy as shown below

```
id     update time                price
5    2015-07-17 09:02:00.000    65.5
5    2015-07-17 09:03:00.000    65.5
5    2015-07-17 09:05:00.000    65.5
5    2015-07-17 09:06:00.000    66
5    2015-07-17 09:07:00.000    66
5    2015-07-17 09:08:00.000    66
5    2015-07-17 09:16:00.000    66.5
5    2015-07-17 09:17:00.000    66.3
5    2015-07-17 09:18:00.000    66.25
5    2015-07-17 09:19:00.000    66.3
5    2015-07-17 09:20:00.000    67.3
5    2015-07-17 09:21:00.000    67.5
```

I want 5min interval date and if next 5min date is not there query should select latest date

i.e 9.02,9.07,9.12 <--not there so it should select 9.16,then 9.21 so on

5 is company id then updTime at last price

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: sql server-2000

Comment: Unfortunately, CTEs (WITH) are not available in SQL Server 2000, which would be a building block for doing this in a single query.  Be aware that the SQL Server 2000 support lifecycle has ended.

Answer (score 4):

For recent versions of SQL-Server that support CTEs (and not the obsolete 2000):

Using a CTE and copying a trick of @Paul White in this answer (to get `TOP` in the recursive part of the CTE): [How to recursively find gaps where 90 days passed, between rows](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83421/how-to-recursively-find-gaps-where-90-days-passed-between-rows/83841#83841)

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    -- Anchor:
    -- Start with the earliest date in the table
    SELECT TOP (1)
        T.id, T.update_time, T.price
    FROM tableX AS T
    ORDER BY
        T.update_time

    UNION ALL

    -- Recursive part   
    SELECT
        SQ1.id, SQ1.update_time, SQ1.price
    FROM 
    (
        -- Recursively find the earliest date that is 
        -- more than 5 minutes after the "current" date
        -- and set the new date as "current".
        -- ROW_NUMBER + rn = 1 is a trick to get
        -- TOP in the recursive part of the CTE
        SELECT
            T.id, T.update_time, T.price,
            rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                ORDER BY T.update_time)
        FROM CTE
        JOIN tableX AS T
            ON T.update_time >= DATEADD(minute, 5, CTE.update_time)
    ) AS SQ1
    WHERE
        SQ1.rn = 1
)
SELECT id, update_time, price 
FROM CTE ;
```

---

A cursor solution, that works in older versions (I don't have a 2000 instance to test and the following will probably need adjustments). Modified from another answer, in the same question [How to recursively find gaps where 90 days passed, between rows](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83421/how-to-recursively-find-gaps-where-90-days-passed-between-rows/83928#83928):

(first, some needed tables and variables):

```
-- a table to hold the results
DECLARE @cd TABLE
(   id INT NOT NULL,                        -- adjust types
    update_time DATETIME PRIMARY KEY,       -- according to 
    price DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL            -- your columns
);

-- some variables
DECLARE
    @id INT,
    @update_time DATETIME,
    @price DECIMAL(10,2),

    @diff INT,
    @previous_update_time DATETIME = '1900-01-01 00:00:00' ;
```

The actual cursor:

```
-- declare the cursor
DECLARE c CURSOR
    LOCAL STATIC FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY
    FOR
    SELECT id, update_time, price
      FROM tableX
      ORDER BY update_time ;

-- using the cursor to fill the @cd table
OPEN c ;

FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @id, @update_time, @price ;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @diff = DATEDIFF(minute, @previous_update_time, @update_time) ;

    IF @diff >= 5
      BEGIN
        INSERT @cd (id, update_time, price)
            VALUES (@id, @update_time, @price) ;

        SET @previous_update_time = @update_time ;
      END ;

    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @id, @update_time, @price ;
END

CLOSE c;
DEALLOCATE c;
```

And getting the results:

```
-- get the results
SELECT id, update_time, price
    FROM @cd
    ORDER BY update_time ;
```

Tested at [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/02393/2) (in 2008 version).

Answer (score -1):

I am not much sure on SQL Server, but this works with PostgreSQL.

Using Recursive CTE to start with the day, more comments are inline.

```
    create table amn1
    (
    id int,
    upd timestamp,
    price float);
     insert into amn1 values
    (5 ,'2015-07-17 09:02:00.000', 65.5),
    (5 ,'2015-07-17 09:03:00.000', 65.5),
    (5 ,'2015-07-17 09:05:00.000', 65.5),
    (5 ,'2015-07-17 09:06:00.000', 66),
    (5 ,'2015-07-17 09:07:00.000', 66),
    (5 ,'2015-07-17 09:08:00.000', 66),
    (5 ,'2015-07-17 09:16:00.000', 66.5),
    (5 ,'2015-07-17 09:17:00.000', 66.3),
    (5 ,'2015-07-17 09:18:00.000', 66.25),
    (5 ,'2015-07-17 09:19:00.000', 66.3),
    (5 ,'2015-07-17 09:20:00.000', 67.3),
    (5 ,'2015-07-17 09:21:00.000', 67.5);

    WITH RECURSIVE dtls (ID, upd, price) AS (
        SELECT
            amn1.ID,
            amn1.upd,
            price
        FROM
            ( 
                SELECT ID, MIN (upd) AS upd 
                FROM amn1 
                WHERE upd >= now() - INTERVAL '1 day'--To Start from today
                GROUP BY ID) T
        INNER JOIN amn1 ON (amn1. ID = T . ID AND amn1.upd = T .upd)--To get today's values
        UNION ALL
            (
                SELECT amn1. ID, amn1.upd, amn1.price 
                FROM
                    amn1
                INNER JOIN dtls ON (amn1. ID = dtls. ID AND amn1.upd >= (dtls.upd + INTERVAL '5 mins'))--Find next earliest updated value
                ORDER BY amn1.upd
                LIMIT 1--Limit with one
            )
    )
    SELECT * FROM dtls
```